# How to makes this script with unlimited Loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript/Jquery Experts,

i have this script.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var number = 1;
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
     if(number == 1){str = "Professionl Designer"}
     else if(number == 2){str = "Professionl Marketer"}
     else if(number == 3){str = "Professionl Programmer"}
     else if(number == 4){str = "Professionl Developer"}    
     $("#test").html("<div>"+ str+"</div>").fadeTo(600, 0.1).fadeTo(600, 1.0);
     ++number;
     if(number == 5){
       clearInterval(timer);
     }
    }, 2500); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "test"></div>
```

check its [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x79tse8t/1/)

This script stops after displaying the last title.

It should display the first title again after displaying the last title in a continual loop.

Comment: Instead of `clearInterval` just reset `number` to one again?

Comment: If you don't want to stop the interval, why do you call `clearInterval(timer);`?

Comment: @vlaz please share code with fiddle. thanks

Comment: @FelixKling please share your fiddle, i dont have much knowledge with that. thanks.

Comment: Literally just do `number = 1` instead of `clearInterval(timer);`

Comment: @FelixKling the script stop on title "Professional Developer" while i want to repeat from first title again. it should not be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the number after each loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pro = ["Professional Designer",
            "Professional Marketer",
            "Professional Programmer",
            "Professional Developer"];

  var number = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
  
    $("#test").html("<div>" + pro[number] + "</div>").fadeTo(600, 0.1).fadeTo(600, 1.0);
    ++number;
    if (number == 4) {
      number = 0;
    }
  }, 2500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Or shorter, with mod `%`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pro = ["Professional Designer",
            "Professional Marketer",
            "Professional Programmer",
            "Professional Developer"];

  var number = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
  
    $("#test").html("<div>" + pro[number] + "</div>").fadeTo(600, 0.1).fadeTo(600, 1.0);
    number = (number+1) %4;
    
  }, 2500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your code. however i would also need one another thing in the script. When every second title display the first one does not completely disappeared. how to do that ? i want to display all titles in slow motion same but every title should must dissappeared completely. For now the first title seems and the second title start appear. i hope you understand my point. thanks.

Comment: This second issue posed in the comment is not part of the original question. If the answer addresses your original question, you should like or up vote, not ask for additional help.

Comment: @RajeshSurry you could make the interval shorter, now it's 2500--change that to the sum of the fadeTo durations (1200) to get a more continuous animation